# JQuery Click inside div

Tags: jquery, click

I am trying to add a click event on a div thats inside a li that already has a click event. I don't want the li click event to fire when the div click event is fired.

Here is the jsfiddle of what I am trying to do.  http://jsfiddle.net/2srUd/5/

When I click on the .inside I don't want the #outside click to fire. I assume I need to ad a not to the selector $(".inside")

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#outside").click(function() {
            alert("outside click");
        });

        $(".inside").click(function() {
            alert("inside click");
        });

    });
</script>
<ul>
    <li id="outside" style="border:2px solid red; padding:20px;">
        <div class="inside" style="border:2px solid blue; ">Click This Div. I want to accept the inside click but not the outside click.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
    $(".inside").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("inside click");
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Basically you don't want it to fire the parent's event handler, so you stop the propagation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me only the outside div ever generates the event. the only difference is that my outside div is a class name not an id if that changes anything `<div class='outer'><div class='inner'>a</div><div class='inner'>b</div></div>`

Answer (score 3):

Just do:    http://jsfiddle.net/2srUd/24/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#outside").click(function() {
            alert("outside click");
        });

        $(".inside").click(function() {  
            alert("inside click");
            return false;
        });

    });
```